# Renren, Weibo, and Baidu Like buttons using only HTML (No Javascript)

Tags: html, url, social-networking, weibo, sinaweibo

I am working on a website that will marketed in China, and I would like to know if there is a method to create "share" buttons for [Renren](http://www.renren.com/) (Similar to Facebook), [Weibo](http://weibo.com/) (Similar to Twitter) and [Baidu Like](http://share.baidu.com/) (Similar to Google's +1) using only HTML.

For example, for Facebook, Twitter and Google's +1 you would use the following:

- http://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com&text=Description
- http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://example.com
- https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=http://example.com

I know that Renren uses the following:

- http://share.renren.com/share/buttonshare.do?link=http://example.com&title=Description

However, **I would love to know what the HTML only URLs for Weibo and Baidu Like are**.

Here is the documentation for the Javascript version of the share buttons if that helps:

- http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/Xn:share-button
- http://open.weibo.com/sharebutton
- http://share.baidu.com/like/get-codes

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hopefully this can help someone in the future; here is how to implement HTML only share/like buttons for Renren, Weibo, and Baidu Like/Space/Forums/Bookmarks:

**Renren**

As mentioned above, use the following URL format to share a link on Renren:

- http://share.renren.com/share/buttonshare.do?link=http://example.com&title=Description

**Weibo**

The following URL format will allow you post to your Weibo account, in the same manner as you would for Twitter:

- http://service.weibo.com/share/share.php?url=http://example.com&appkey=&title=Description&pic=&ralateUid=&language=zh_cn

**Baidu**

Baidu has multiple services that can be posted to; the one relevant to this post is Baidu Like, but I have provided URLs for Baidu Space, Forums, and Bookmarks for reference as well:

To like a link in in the same manner as Facebook/Google +1, using the following URL structure:

- http://like.baidu.com/set?buttontype=small&cb=bdShare.ajax._callbacks.bd4bb141b&index=0&url=http://example.com

I tracked the above URLs down using a packet analyser, and as far as I can tell, Baidu Like has to be called from the referring page, or at the very least, the referring domain. The callback function `bd4bb141b` does not seem to be specific to any domain or user ID.

---

Please note that I have *not* tested the following URLs structures thoroughly:

- To share a link on Baidu Space, use the following URL structure: http://apps.hi.baidu.com/share/?url=http://example.com&title=Description
- To share a link on Baidu Tieba (Forums), use the following URL structure: http://tieba.baidu.com/i/app/open_share_api?link=http://example.com
- To save a link to Baidu Cang (Bookmarks), use the following URL structure: http://cang.baidu.com/do/add?it=Description&iu=http://example.com

---

Also for reference, a good Chinese alternative to [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.google.com/) is [FeedSky](http://www.feedsky.com/).

Comment: If Baidu Like fails, you will get the following message: `bdShare.ajax._callbacks.bd4bb141b({"index":0,"count":7,"err":1,"err_msg":"\u60a8\u5df2\u8bc4\u4ef7\uff01\u8c22\u8c22"})`. The error message in Chinese is "您已评价！谢谢", which basically means the request has been noted, but no action has been taken. If Baidu Like succeeds, you will get the following message: `bdShare.ajax._callbacks.bd4bb141b({"index":0,"count":8,"err":0,"err_msg":"ok"})`.

Comment: I found this post very helpful thanks for the info! Facebook sharer.php is deprecated does anyone know if the Weibo share.php is deprecated as well? I can't seem to find a lot of info on it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use Weibo but sometimes it works others it does not. Probably it is deprecated too. The problem is that the site is in Chinese.

Comment: @rtacconi I noticed that too; I don't know if this helps, but I noticed it works only when it is called from the actual URL. i.e. If you call it from a testing server, it will detect that the referrer doesn't match and deny the request.

Comment: @AndrewOdri it actually works for localhost but not for the actual URL!

Comment: @rtacconi I'm currently trying to use the Weibo share link. It seems to work well, even without specifying an appKey. But I'm testing it from a local test server, so... have you guys experienced any problem with it on a live website? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to set the "source" on the shared post in Weibo, any idea what other parameters weibo/share.php expects?

Comment: In 2019, the Weibo link still works, but the one for Renren returns 404 Not Found

Answer (score 3):

With my own site (currently) the share button does not show up when using httpS ... but it does with http

Here is the link to the most recent (November 10th, 2015) Weibo share button code generator (scroll to the bottom to get the code):

http://open.weibo.com/sharebutton